# how to add input boxes horizontally on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I need to add text input boxes aligned horizontally on the click of a button
Every time i click "add attribute" a new input box should be created but placed horizontally right the previous input box. Is there a way to do this in vue.js

This adds input boxes, but vertically one below the other, i want them to be horizontally aligned

```
<hr>
<div class="md-layout">
    <md-button v-on:click="addKey" class="md-raised md-primary">Add Attribute</md-button>
</div>
<md-content class="md-scrollbar" style="max-width:90vh; overflow: auto">
    <div class="md-layout" v-for="value, index in keyList">
        <md-field>
            <md-input type="text" v-model="value.key" v-bind:id="'keyInput' + index" @keyup.enter="searchKey(value.key, index)"
                @focus="updateKey(index)">
            </md-input>
            <md-input type="text" v-model="value.key" v-bind:id="'keyInput' + index" @keyup.enter="searchKey(value.key, index)"
                @focus="updateKey(index)">
            </md-input>
            <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" :id="'keyButton' + index" @click="removeKey(index)"> X </md-button>
        </md-field>
    </div>
```

Comment: which library you're working with?

Comment: Can you provide your `addKey` method? @Developer

Comment: This is mostly to do with with the styles you use, are you using angular material design here?

Comment: i am working with js and css

Answer (score 1):

This CSS should work

```
input { display: inline; }
```

Comment: could you please let me know how will it fit in the code i have shared. Thanks

Comment: you have to add a <style> tag and put the css inside. In this way all the input elements will be aligned horizontally

Answer (score 0):

Kindly add flex in display attribute as it provide horizontal alignment to the 
controls by default.

```
<md-field style="display: flex;">
```

Comment: Could you add some more detail to your answer so that people who come across the same issue, can use your solution as well?

Comment: Yes sure.. @creyD